# Get data from remote SQLite

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

First, I created " subjects.sqlite " and insert it to the Xcode files " Copy Bundle Resrources "

I used this code

```
NSData *fetchedData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.precaliga.com/iphone/subjects.sqlite"]];
    NSString *documentsPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
    NSString *filePath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"subjects.sqlite"];
    [fetchedData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];

    NSFileManager *fileMgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    BOOL success = [fileMgr fileExistsAtPath:filePath];
    if (!success) {
        NSLog(@"Cannot locate database file '%@'.", filePath);
    }
    else {
        self.db = [DBController sharedDatabaseController:filePath];
        DataTable* table = [_db  ExecuteQuery:@"SELECT * FROM subjects"];
        NSLog(@"%@",table.columns);
        NSLog(@"Downloaded Successfuly ..");
    }
```

But " table.columns " return

2013-04-12 11:34:06.202 Precaliga[82123:c07] (
)

Because it doesn't read the downloaded sqlite file. so how could I read data after downloaded function

Thanks in advance .. please help me

Comment: NSLog(@"%d",fetchedData.length); This should not be zero. Check this.

Comment: It show: 983040 , not zero .. the file is downloaded but I can't fetch data from the sqlite !! what is the solution ?

Comment: Are you able to see file in your doc dir ?

Comment: Could you give me the location to see ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
NSData *fetchedData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.precaliga.com/iphone/subjects.sqlite"]];
NSLog(@"%d",fetchedData.length);
NSString *documentsPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
NSString *filePath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"subjects.sqlite"];
if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePath])
     [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:filePath contents:fetchedData attributes:nil];
[fetchedData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];

NSFileManager *fileMgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

BOOL success = [fileMgr fileExistsAtPath:filePath];
if (!success)
{
    NSLog(@"Cannot locate database file '%@'.", filePath);
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"Downloaded Successfuly ..");
}
```

**EDIT**

Write these in your AppDelegate.m

```
- (void) copyDatabaseIfNeeded
{
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSError *error;
    NSString *folderPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask,YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    // First, test for existence.
    if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:folderPath])
        [fileManager createDirectoryAtPath:folderPath withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:&error]; //Create folder

    NSString *dbPath = [folderPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"subjects.sqlite"];
    BOOL success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:dbPath];

    if(!success)
    {
        NSString *defaultDBPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"subjects.sqlite"];
        success = [fileManager copyItemAtPath:defaultDBPath toPath:dbPath error:&error];
        if (!success)
            NSAssert1(0, @"subjects.sqlite : Failed to create writable database file with message '%@'.", [error localizedDescription]);
    }
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    /** Database copy is not exist **/
    [self copyDatabaseIfNeeded]; // Call this way
}
```

Comment: Try this code once and look at path you can see in this variable - filePath. Check in simulator first.

Comment: It show downloaded successfuly, I add NSLog(@"Downloaded Successfuly ..");
        self.db = [DBController sharedDatabaseController:@"subjects.sqlite"];
        DataTable* table = [_db  ExecuteQuery:@"SELECT * FROM subjects"];
        NSLog(@"%@",table.columns);

Comment: Check out your database in document directory

Comment: filePath is = /Users/*/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.1/Applications/89FCA092-AEEA-499E-A39F-C8EFAE9BEDBF/Documents/subjects.sqlite , but still not return any data

Comment: I check the document directory, there is no subjects.sqlite !! I think it is not copied there what is the solution ?

Comment: I will try it soon .. Must go i will reply soon thanks for help dear

Comment: it show now in Documents .. but how can I call it from Documents as : self.db = [DBController sharedDatabaseController:@"subjects.sqlite"];

Comment: What do you think mr. @bhargavi

Comment: Well its not 'mr.' its ms. here. and what is wrong with your code. Figure it out + search on google for accessing database in ios. :)

Comment: Ah ok ms. @bhargavi , I will update the post soon for complete solution , thanks alot